# Excel - Code for a row line in source

Tags: excel, csv, delimiter

All

I am trying to change the "delimiters" in my csv file, so I can open it as an excel file.

I know the delimiter to separeate the columns is ';'. But what is the delimiter for a new line?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For windows machines: `vbCrLf` or `Chr(13) & Chr(10)`
Carriage Return then Line Feed

If you are going to be using this code on multiple platforms, then `vbNewLine` will be whatever is needed for the platform (windows/unix/mac/whatever)

Comment: I currently use 'ETB' as separator (I can't paste the sign in here, it is something like '-|' How can I change this with Chr(13) ?

Comment: the format for a CSV file is a comma between items, double quotes around text, and a new line for the end of a record. White out your data in this format, and excel will be able to import it