# Transform flat datatable to dataset using XSD

Tags: xml, vb.net, xsd, flat-file

Can anyone advise me if this is possible?

I have data in textform that looks like this:

```
...
^GLOBAL HDORDNOLBL
^GLOBAL HDORDNO
^GLOBAL ORDDATLBL
Orderdatum
^GLOBAL ORDDAT
01/06/12
^GLOBAL INVDATLBL
Fact.datum
^GLOBAL INVDAT
05/06/12
^GLOBAL COUNTRYLBL
^GLOBAL COUNTRY
Belgium
^GLOBAL CUSNOLBL
Klantennummer
^GLOBAL CUSNO
AL8985
...
```

I'll be putting this in a flat datatable with `^[ITEM]` being a field and `[VALUE]` being the value. I can manage this BUT... I would like to transform this datatable into a dataset based on certain rules. Basically, what I want to do is make a structured dataset from flat data. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use find/replace to [change the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750162/excel-code-for-a-row-line-in-source) to CSV format, import the flat file into Excel as CSV, then use a [VBA macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558013/save-as-xml-with-vba) to convert it to XML using the XSD.

Comment: I've ceated my own xml file to use and create structure in the flat data file. (groups, exceptions, ...) Anyhow, if you're data has to be transformed to a "flat" xml file the answer above is indeed (one of) the way(s) to do it.